# Table inside a div - contents of td causes horizontal overflow. How can I constrain the width?

Tags: css, html-table, overflow, clipping

http://jsfiddle.net/HeMKY/8/

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">left</td>
            <td class="right"><span>this text is right-floated</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">left</td>
            <td class="right"><img src="foo.gif" height="100" width="400" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="left">left</td>
            <td class="right">THISTEXTISWAYTOOLONGTHISTEXTISWAYTOOLONGTHISTEXTISWAYTOOLONG</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
    max-width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:gray;
    padding:5px;
}
td
{
    padding:5px;
}
td.left
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
td.right
{
    background-color:green;
}
td.right span
{
    float:right;
}
```

RESULT

[image: overflow]

WHAT I WANT

[image: overflow is clipped]

Note how both images and text could cause overflows. Also, some content that naturally fits is right-floated, so I can't just do `overflow:hidden` or else that naturally-fitting content gets hidden as well. I also need to enable `.left` to stretch to fit its contents, i.e. the content there could range in width from 10-150px and I want that column to be no wider than its widest content. As far as I know, this isn't possible without tables so that's why I'm using a table instead of `table-layout:fixed` or a CSS grid framework.

I was hoping some combination of `width:100%` or `max-width:100%;` on the `table` or `tr` would do the trick, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: perhaps it would help to not have a 400px image in a table that you want to be 300px?

Comment: based on responses below I think it would help if you told us what browsers and versions you need to support.

Comment: IE7+, FF 3.5+, Chrome, Safari 4+, mobile safari, android 2.1+ stock browser, and WP7 (IE7-ish)

Answer (score 2):

You can add `word-break:break-all;` to your td. However, you will still have a problem with your image. What do you expect to happen with the image? You can't wrap an image so it either needs to be hidden or smaller. I don't think there is a workaround for that.

After learning that this isn't supported by FF, which I guess I kind of knew in the back of my mind I did some more research. From what I found you can't do it. There are two hacks you can work in.

First one is to use the  tag as discussed by [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html). Downside being that it isn't supported everywhere.

The other is to insert a space character that is [extremely narrow](http://www.matsblog.com/stories/778902/). This gives the table cell something to break on. Hopefully somebody else can come up with a better, standards compliant answer, but I can't find one.

Comment: updated my answer after some research. upvoted your question so that hopefully a better answer comes through.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you try `table-layout: fixed` [as shown here](http://jsfiddle.net/HeMKY/16/) (works in ie6+, firefox, & chrome)

Combined with defining `width: 40px`(or whatever) for your left column and setting `overflow-x: hidden` on the right column, you should achieve the desired affect.

Comment: i tried that as well but `table-layout:fixed` isn't fully supported in the browsers i need to support

Comment: thanks for looking at it again. i mentioned in another comment i need `.left` to stretch to fit its contents, whether it is 15px or 150px. I don't want to set a fixed width on that column. as far as i know, this isn't possible without tables

Answer (score 1):

Seeing what you want to do, instead of using a `table`, consider using Blueprint's grid.

[This page](http://www.blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html) shows what it can do, and it is all achieved by simply importing their `grid.css` file in your html document and adding some divs with specific class names.

You can download Blueprint [here](http://www.blueprintcss.org/) and then read *h3. Creating a Grid* paragraph in the *TUTORIAL.textile* in the download.

Comment: i've considered using a css framework, but unfortunately it doesn't meet my needs. primarily, i need `.left` to stretch to fit its contents, whether it is 15px or 150px. as far as i know, this isn't possible without tables (or at the least, not supported in older browsers)